# Ignoring NaN/null values while looping through data

Tags: python, pandas

I wasn't able to find any clear answers on what I assume to be a simple question.  This is for Python 3.  What are some of your tips and tricks when applying functions, loops, etc... on your data when your column has both null and non null values?

Here is the example I ran into when I was cleaning some data today. I have a function that takes two columns from my merged dataframe then calculates a ratio showing how similar two strings are.

imports:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import difflib
import os
from functools import partial
import datetime
```

my function:

```
def apply_sm(merged, c1, c2):
        return difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, merged[c1], merged[c2]).ratio()
```

Here is me calling the function in my code example:

```
merged['NameMatchRatio'] = merged.apply(partial(apply_sm, c1='CLIENT NAME', c2='ClientName'), axis=1)
```

CLIENT NAME has no null values, while ClientName does have null values (which throw out errors when I try to apply my function).  How can I apply my function while ignoring the NaN values (in either column just in case)?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [math.isnan](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) to check if a value is nan and skip it. Alternatively, you can also replace nan with zero or something else and then apply your function on it. It really depends on what you want to achieve.

A simple example:

```
import math

test_variable = math.nan    
if math.isnan(test_variable):
    print("it is a nan value")
```

Just incorporate this logic into your code as you deem fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
def apply_sm(merged, c1, c2):
  if not merged[[c1,c2]].isnull().any():
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, merged[c1], merged[c2]).ratio()
  return 0.0 # <-- you could handle the Null case here
```